# Script size passed to Informix via ODBC

Tags: sql-insert, informix, temp-tables

I'm trying to ascertain if there are any limits to the size of a script passed to Informix via ODBC.

My Informix script size is going to run into a few megabytes (approximately 3.5K `INSERT` rows to a `TEMP` table), and is of the form...

```
INSERT INTO table (field_1, field_2) VALUES (value_1, value_2)
INSERT INTO table (field_1, field_2) VALUES (value_1, value_2)
...
INSERT INTO table (field_1, field_2) VALUES (value_1, value_2)
```

...followed by a section to return a `SELECT` list based on an existing table...

```
SELECT 
    t1.field_1, 
    t1.field_2, 
    ...
    t1.field_n, 
    t2.field_2  
FROM 
    table_1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    temp_table_2 AS t2 
        ON  t1.field_1 = t2.field_1
```

Are there any limits to the size of the script, or, for that matter, the memory table?  I'm estimating (hoping?) that 3.5K rows (we're only looking at one or two columns) would not cause an issue, or affect the server in an adverse way (there's easily be enough memory).  Please note that my only communication method is via ODBC, and this is a proprietary database - I cannot create actual data tables on the server.

The reason I'm asking, is that, previously, I generated a script that was a considerable size, but, instead of putting the 3.5k IDs in a `TEMP` table (with associated data), I used an `IN` condition to look for the IDs only (processing could take place once the records were located).  However, I cannot be certain whether it was the script editor (which was some kind of interface to the database) that baulked, limits to the `IN` condition, or the size of the script itself, that caused a problem, but basically the script would not run.  After this we VIed a script, saving it to a folder and attempted to execute this, with similar (but not the same) results (sorry - I don't have the error messages from either process - this was done a little while ago).

Any Informix oriented tips for in this area would really be appreciated!  :o)

Comment: It would be helpful if your `temp_table_2` and `table` names were matched, if they are supposed to be the same table.  It might be relevant to know how big `table_1` is — presumably considerably bigger than `temp_table_2` in both 'size of each row' and probably 'number of rows'.  Is there a good reason not to keep the 3,500 value pairs in a permanent table?  You can create indexes on temp tables, IIRC, and an index on `temp_table_2.field_1` might improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Informix are you using?  Assuming it is either 12.10 or 14.10, then there is no specific limit on the size of a set of statements, but a monstrosity like you're proposing is cruel and unusual punishment for a database server (it is definitely abusing your server).

It can also be moderately risky; you have to ensure you quote any data provided by the user correctly to avoid the problem of [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327).

You should be preparing one INSERT statement with two placeholder values:

```
INSERT INTO table(field_1, field_2) VALUES(?,?)
```

You should then execute this repeatedly, providing the different values.  This will be more effective than making the server parse 3,500 similar statements.  In ESQL/C, you can declare an INSERT cursor which will buffer the sets of values, reducing the round trips to the server — that can also be very valuable.  I'm not sure whether that's an option in ODBC; probably not.

At the very least, you should experiment with using a prepared statement.  Sending 3,500 x 60+ bytes = 210 KiB to the server is doable.  But you'd be sending less volume of data to the server (but there'd be more round trips — which can be a factor) if you use the prepared statement and execute it repeatedly with new parameters each time.  And you avoid the security risks of converting the values to strings.  (Since you've not stated the types of the values, it's not certain there's a risk.  If they're numeric, or things like date and time, they're very low risk.  If they're character strings, the risk of is considerable — not insuperable, but not negligible.)

Older versions of Informix had smaller limits on the size of a set of statements — 64 KiB, and before that, 32 KiB.  You're unlikely to be using an old enough version for that to be a problem, but the rules have changed over time.

Comment: Fortunately, Bobby Tables was sacked some time ago - all values are being read from (another proprietary) SQL Server table. The data is being pulled and pushed by an application, as I can't add the Informix middleware to the SQL Server, either (if it were that simple, I'd just create a linked server!) *{puts head in hands}*.  From what I'm seeing, I suspect that we're using a version of Informix prior to version 12......  I'll check a few things and get back to you.  Thanks for your input to this it is *really* appreciated.

Comment: ...also, I did use a similar process as mentioned previously, but the process was taking quite a while.  I may have to revisit this code and see if I've got anything stupid in the way.